# ViewWillAppear on UITableViewCell?

Tags: swift, uitableview, viewwillappear

Is there any way to perform something like ViewWillAppear on UITableViewCell?

UITableViewDelegate methods (like willDisplayCell) only works when cells appear by scrolling.

In my situation, I need to detect cell appearance in a situation like user moves to another Tab and gets back to the UITableView.

I was able to solve the my problem using indexPathsForVisibleRows method but this doesn't seem to be a smart way of doing it.

Comment: What do you want to perform when user came back from another tab ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes. you have to use `awakeFromNib` meyhod inside the m file. this method is always call first.

```
-(void)awakeFromNib{

}
```

if visible cell not load then you have to reload your tableview.

```
 tableView.reloadData()
```

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but awakeFronNib is not called in a case like a user moves to another Tab and gets back to the UITableView.

Comment: @Bigair awakeFromNib is called only when first of cell load like in UIViewController

Comment: @Bigair one anothyer way to load previus tableview cell is  reload your tableview when it clicks on another **Tab**

Comment: "calling tableView.reloadData() in the UITableView viewWillAppear" as Vvk Aghera suggested was a perfect solution.  This should be an accepted answer.  Great and very smart solution, thanks a lot.

Comment: I didn't realize tableView.reloadData() solution was on the answer, I just accepted the answer

Answer (score 7):

I'm not sure whether this will work for you as you want to do something on tab change as well otherwise it will work.

I know I am answering too late, but I am answering to help others who view this post.

So you can try this:
(Objective-C)

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell  
                                         forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // Do what ever you want
}
```

(Swift)

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, willDisplayCell cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
    // Do what ever you want
}
```

Comment: I tried to use this method (swift) but I got an error to remove "override" -"Method does not override any method from its superclass". When I remove the "override" the app compiles but the method is not called, although other delegate methods are called (such as "didSelectRowAtIndexPath")

Comment: @Zvi, Thanks. Updated my answer. Can you try following method instead of willDisplayCell and let me know your result: func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)

Comment: First need to use indexPath: NSIndexPath (mistake even in Apple documentation). Second, I do not know what I did but now it works, using willDisplayCell - willDisplay does still not working